# How to change background to put particles.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, particles

I bought the template 'Penelope' from Envato and I want to change the background with a particles.js background. This is the original CSS that provides me this template. I want to know how to change it to put the particles.js background.

I've the plugin on my repost, I only want to know how to put it. I'm a newbie on this.

Thank you so much.

CSS:

```css
  background: transparent url("../img/mainbg.jpg") no-repeat;
  image-rendering: optimizeQuality;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  position: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
  -o-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Give you Particle js backgroud property `position:absolute` like this

```
#particles-js>canvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

then give it the height and width you want in your case i think its 100%.
set-up the z-index as you want to see where its suiting